# Не сохраняются сессии в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Раньше было все отлично и все работало. Вчера заметил, что не показываются ошибки формы. Сегодня пробую пофиксить это, и пришел к выводу, что вообще не работают сессии.

Файлы в `storage` создаются, значит проблемы не с правами (хотя их я тоже проверил).

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Это тоже использую.

Не могу понять в чем еще может быть проблема. У кого какие идеи?

**Форма**:

```
<form action="{{ route('objectEdit', $object) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf

  @if(session('message'))
    @include('layouts.account.alerts.message', [
      'alert' => session('message'),
    ])
  @endif

  @php
    dump(session()->all());
  @endphp

  @if($errors->any())
    @include('layouts.account.alerts.danger', [
      'alert' => 'Ошибки формы',
    ])
  @endif

  <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $object->name) }}">

  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

**Request**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EditObject extends FormRequest
{
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
      'name' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'max:255'
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public function update(EditObject $request, SportObject $object)
{
  if(!CheckObjectTrait::check($object)) {
    return redirect()->back();
  }

  // dd($request->all());
  // ...остальной код.

  return redirect()->route('objectEditForm', $object)->with('message', 'Test message');
}
```

Comment: 1. session_start вызывается?
2. локалка\хостинг\виртуальная машина?

Comment: Смотрите логи в storage/logs

Comment: @k0mar обычная локалка php artisan serve. А как 1 посмотреть? :)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в логах ничего по сессиям

Comment: Запускайте отладку и смотрите где и что происходит, так как это запуск PHP Built-in сервера из-под консоли - трудно сказать что может быть не так.

Comment: @РустамГимранов добавил

Comment: @РустамГимранов ошибки - валидатор Request + есть еще сообщение пользователю в сессии ('message')

Comment: @РустамГимранов да, валидатор работает, просто сообщений нет. Этот трейт я позже заменю. Он провиряет наличеи ИД юзера в объекте

Comment: Значит, вспоминайте, какие настройки меняли в директории `config`. А значение в поле ввода `{{ old('name', $object->name) }}` сохраняется?

Comment: @РустамГимранов В конфиге вообще ничего не менял. За дебагер - спасибо)

Comment: @РустамГимранов old тоже не сохраняет

Comment: Ну напоследок: 1) маршрут не использует посредник `web` 2) закэшируйте для профилактики `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов да! Заработало! У меня два раза использовался \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, Спасибо вам большое! День потратил!)